# how to make wordpress website work online with Ip and locally using localhost with IP bind or other

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp, localhost

Please help me. I have a wordpress website running on apache xampp server on windows server 2012 R2. It works perfectly on web server when i set site url settings in wordpress to https://localhost.

When i try to access it using Web server ip on other online systems. images and css files does not load , links does not work. So i change Wordpress Site url setting to https:// and it works on other computers. But  now it is not accessible on  web server.

Kindly help if anyone knows, how is it possible by keeping https://localhost under wordpress site settings and  make it accessible to others systems on internet. I want to make it accessible online and on our web server (Localhost).

I do not know properly, but is it possible  to bind ip address with apache, so it may work online as well as locally using localhost.

Thanks